# How does jquery set offset () values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

How does jquery do to set offset values of an element?Does it change its css values?I am becoming mad trying to understand.

Comment: I was recently surprised to learn how it calculates it - Have a look at http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#offset it uses values from getBoundingClientRect

Comment: If you want to see what it's doing, open Developer Tools and look at the DOM element before and after you change the offset.

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery source code? Have a look and you'll see exactly how it does it.

Comment: I didn't manage to find the source code of this method

Answer (score 0):

If you set $('#element').offset({ top : 20}) it will result in inline styles of - style="position: relative; top: 12px;" - at least in my browser.

```js
$('#element').offset({ top : 20})
```

```html
<div id="element">hello</div>
```